# HTML Special Characters (foreign languages)

Tags: php

Basically I have this string:

```
Český, Deutsch, English (US), Español (ES), Français (France), Italiano, 日本語, 한국어, Polski, 中文（繁體)
```

And I want to convert it into all possible HTML entities (there might be russian characters too!).
I've tried to make different "htmlspecialchars" and "htmlentities" function with different charsets but it returns empty strings...

```
$l = htmlentities("Český, Deutsch, English (US), Español (ES), Français (France), Italiano, 日本語, 한국어, Polski, 中文（繁體） €", ENT_COMPAT, "BIG5-HKSCS");
$l = htmlentities($l, ENT_COMPAT, "KOI8-R");
$l = htmlentities($l, ENT_COMPAT, "EUC-JP");
$l = htmlentities($l, ENT_COMPAT, "Shift_JIS");
$l = htmlentities($l, ENT_COMPAT, "Shift_JIS");
echo $l;
```

returns an empty string.

Any help?

Comment: what's your php version?

Comment: use `phpinfo()` to find out

Comment: Not working, what change?

Comment: print this as a 3m x 1m standard and hung it across your office room: `UTF-8, UTF-8 everywhere`. Believe me, using always UTF8 will save you from a lot of pain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my "unutf8" function, which converts all UTF8 characters into HTML entities of the form `&#12345;`

```
function unutf8($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback("([\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}|[\xF8-\xFB][\x80-\xBF]{4}|[\xFC-\xFD][\x80-\xBF]{5})",
        function($m) {
            $c = $m[0];
            $out = bindec(ltrim(decbin(ord($c[0])),"1"));
            $l = strlen($c);
            for( $i=1; $i<$l; $i++) {
                $out = ($out<<6) | bindec(ltrim(decbin(ord($c[$i])),"1"));
            }
            if( $out < 256) return chr($out);
            return "&#".$out.";";
        },$str);
}
```

It parses the string for valid UTF8 character sequences and converts the multi-byte sequence into the ordinal value of the character. It's very messy and I don't expect to win any awards for good coding with this, but it works.

Please note, however, that if you have unencoded characters then you WILL run into problems. For example, if for some reason you have é©© then the result will be 驩. Please make sure your string is valid UTF8 before passing it to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Use header to modify the HTTP header to utf-8:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Also, make sure your HTML document is also in utf-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for tough solutions and just follow this small and simple steps :
1) mysql_set_charset("utf8", $conn); set this with your config connection code.

or

2) mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
enter your query here........
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", queryResult);